# Returning 2d array of pointers in c++

Tags: c++, arrays, class, 2d

I have a class and another class with class member of 2d array from the first class type.
and I need a function that returns that class member.

```
class Piece
{
    // something is implemented here/ 
};

class Board
{
private:
    Piece* _pieces[8][8];
public:
    Piece*** getPieces()
    {
       return _pieces;
    }
}
```

but that's not working.

Comment: Arrays are not pointers. And either way, even attempting to return a non-const pointer to your instance data is ill-advised. Major break in encapsulation.

Comment: [Three Star Programmer](http://wiki.c2.com/?ThreeStarProgrammer).

Comment: Please use vectors but for reference it should only be `**` as the declaration should be `Piece _pieces[8][8];`

Comment: You don't *really* want to return the whole board, you want to have query functions like `bool is_king(square);` or actions `void move(square from, square to);`.

Comment: this smells like cargo-cult programming to me, why did you declare it private in the first place? Just to struggle to make it public again?

Comment: For reference your function should be declared `Piece* (*getPieces())[8] { return _pieces; }` but better not to return the board at all  and to use `std::array` as I suggested above.

Comment: Consider `std::array<std::array<Piece*, 8>, 8> _pieces;`

Answer (score 0):

This is a quick version of your class I made to allow the passing of the 2d array to work.

```
class Board
{
private:
    Piece ** _pieces = new Piece*[8];
public:
    Board()
    {
        for(int i = 0; i<8; i++)
        _pieces[i] = new Piece[8];
    }
    Piece** getPieces()
    {
       return _pieces;
    }
    ~Board()
    {
        for(int i = 0; i<8; i++) delete [] _pieces[i];

        delete [] _pieces;
    }
};
```

Comment: But your code doesn't store 2D array of _pointers_ to `Piece`, as OP intended.

Comment: On the other hand, while this might be what the OP *asked* for, what he really *needs*  is a member `Piece _pieces[64];` and skip the getter. Otherwise he will create the world's slowest chess program.

Answer (score 0):

You could std::array to create 2D array of pointers if you have access to C++11/14/17, it's a lot cleaner and expressive than using the build in array that decay to a ptr. 
What follows is an example of  how you create and return from Booard a 8x8 2D array of pointers to Pieces.

```
#include <array>
class Piece
{
// something is implemented here/ 
};
using Pieces=std::array<std::array<Piece*,8>,8>;
class Board
{
private:
Pieces _pieces;
public:
const Pieces& getPieces()
{
   return _pieces;
}
};
```

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by @Galik in comment, you should use std::arrays here, because the sizes are constant expressions.

It is not really mandated by the standard, but for common implementations, a `std::array<std::array<T,i>,j>` does have a true `T[i][j]` 2D array as underlying data - said differently, consecutive rows use adjacent memory. `std::vector` on another hand acts more as an array of pointers and data of consecutive rows are generally not adjacent in memory.

Code could become:

```
class Board
{
private:
    std::array<std::array<Piece*, 8>, 8> _pieces;
public:
    std::array<std::array<Piece*, 8>, 8>& getPieces()
    {
       return _pieces;
    }
}
```

But this is still poor design, because it unnecessarily exposes the underlying implementation, so you really should think twice on what should be the public methods for the `Board` class.

Answer (score -1):

for example, 
int   a[3][6];
int **p=a;    // it's wrong

You should use pointer like this:

int  (*p)[6];
p=a;